# Infinite expected number of visits with Green function

Tags: probability, random-walk

The random walk Green function is defined by $G(x,1) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0} P(S_n = x)$,  with $x\in\mathbb{Z}^d$.

$G(x,1)$ equals the expected number of visits to $x$.

Now I want to prove that $G(0,1)=\infty$ if and only if $G(x,1)=\infty$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}^d$. This looks clear for $x = 0$. But how can I prove this for general $x$?

Comment: This is NOT clear for 0. Depending on the walk, this can be false. Suppose you always take a step (1,...,1). Then the estimated number of returns is 0.

Comment: Also the statement looks false. Take a walk that remain on 0. Or one that alternates between 0 and one of its neighbor.